# Custom interaction in the PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, image, properties, propertygrid

I have two custom classes:

```
class Something
{
}
```

and:

```
class SomethingElse
{
public Something newSomething {get;set;}
public String aName {get;set;}
public Image aPicture {get;set;}
//etc...
}
```

At the moment, when I select the `class SomethingElse` during runtime, it populates my `PropertyGrid`, showing me all my properties with their relative interactions.
Ie, where it says "aPicture" there is a *textbox* field and a *button [...]* where I can click and it opens a dialogue view window to select an image.

How can I add this functionality to my custom class? So when the propertygrid view shows *newSomething* it displays a textbox and a button ?

I'm completely lost with this, not even sure what/where I would need to look.
I've looked into the `Image class`, but I couldnt see anything obvious there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You say "when I select the class SomethingElse during runtime" - it's not clear what you mean by this.  Do you mean to say "create an object based on the class SomethingElse at runtime"?

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class has a custom [Editor attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) setup which defines a class that derives from the base [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) class, if you look at it with a tool such as .NET Reflector, you will see this:

```
[... Editor("System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor, System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))...]
public abstract class Image : ...
{
   ...
}
```

So you can do the same with your class, like this:

```
[Editor(typeof(MySomethingEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public class Something
{
   ...
}

public class MySomethingEditor: UITypeEditor
{
   ...
}
```

You can google on "UITypeEditor" to get some samples. Here is one official one: [Walkthrough: Implementing a UI Type Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx)

Comment: i found the [Editor] attrb, but had no idea what to do with it
thank you so much !
that Walkthrough is perfect for me!